# Custom Controls are not displaying in MobileVLCKit media player

Tags: swift, ios10, libvlc

I am using MobileVLCKit in my swift project. I am using cocoapod **MobileVLCKit-prod(2.7)**. I want to add video controls to player. This is the my code.

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)
       let filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "bunny", withExtension: "webm")
       self.mediaPlayer.media = VLCMedia(url: filePath)
       self.mediaPlayer.drawable = self.view
       self.addVideoControls()
       self.mediaPlayer.play()
```

}

```
func addVideoControls() {
    let videoControls = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.maxX, height: 60.0))
    videoControls.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    let videoView = self.mediaPlayer.drawable as! UIView
    videoView.addSubview(videoControls)
    videoView.bringSubview(toFront: videoControls)
}
```

VLC team provided explore is not compiling. How to customize the video player.please understand me what is the wrong in my code.

Comment: Have you tried adding a standard `UIView` to make sure this isn't an issue with the `MPVolumeView` component?

Comment: For a functioning VLCKit Swift example project you could check out https://github.com/niklasberglund/vlckitSwiftSample

Comment: @Niklas Berglund I am able to play the videos. In above project there is no seeker or other controls. I took support from VLC team. Now I am able to add all controls.

Comment: @mahbaleshwarhegde , Hii am having same problem, How did you you achieve this. can you please explain ?